# Bot isn't responding to my command | discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I was making a work command, and I needed some help. The bot was not responding unless I put my id into the json file instead of the bot doing it automatically. I don't get any error either. Again, it only works unless I manually put the id into the json file.
Here's the code:

```py
youtuber = {}

def youtube():
  global youtuber
  try:
    with open ('youtuber.json', "a") as f:
      youtuber = json.load(f)
  except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File not found")

developer = {}

def developing():
  global developer
  try:
    with open('developer.json', "a") as f:
        developer = json.load(f)
  except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Error")

scientist = {}

def science():
  global scientist
  try:
    with open('scientist.json', "a") as f:
        scientist = json.load(f)
  except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Error")

    @commands.command()
    async def work(self, ctx):
      await open_account(ctx.author)
      #Variables
      salary = 2000
      id = str(ctx.author.id)
      #If user is unemployed :laughard:
      if id not in developer and scientist and youtuber:
        await ctx.send("Your unemployed, You can work as a `developer` or a `scientist` or a `youtuber` or a `doctor`. Pick one.\n\nNote: All jobs have the same amount of salary")
        message = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check = lambda: message.author ==  ctx.author)
        #Developer
        if message.content == "developer":
          developer[id] = 1
          with open('developer.json', 'a') as f:
            json.dump(developer, f) 
          await ctx.send("Congratualations! You now work as a developer!")
          return
        #youtuber
        elif message.content == "youtuber":
          youtuber[id] = 1
          with open('scientist.json', 'a') as f:
            json.dump(scientist, f)
            await ctx.send("Congratualations! You now work as a youtuber!")
            return
        #scientist
        elif message.content == "scientist":
          scientist[id] = 1
          with open('youtuber.json', 'a') as f:
            json.dump(youtuber, f) 
          await ctx.send("Congratualations! You now work as a scientist!")
          return
      #Dev work
      elif id in developer:
        dev_work = ["Type the following: `Python is the best. Everything else is trash.`", "Type the following: `Time to steal some code.`", "Answer the following question: `Which is the best bot in the world?`"]
        rand_dev = random.choice(dev_work)
        await ctx.send(rand_dev)
        message = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda : message.author == ctx.author)
        if rand_dev == dev_work[0]:
          if message.content == "Python is the best. Everything else is trash.":
            await ctx.send("You have earned 2000 coins!")
          else:
            await ctx.send("You can't even type a sentence properly? You get 0 coins")
            return
        elif rand_dev == dev_work[1]:
          if message.content == "Time to steal some code.":
            await ctx.send("You have earned 2000 coins!")
          else:
            await ctx.send("You can't even type a sentence properly? Dumb")
            return
        elif rand_dev == dev_work[2]:
          if message.content == "LeBot":
            await ctx.send("You have earned 2000 coins!")
          else:
            await ctx.send("It's LeBot......")
            return
      #Youtube work
      elif id in youtuber:
        youtuber_work = ["Type the following: `I wish I had 100mil sub's like pewdiepie.`", "Type the following: `The Hair Trilogy is the best trilogy to ever exist.`", "Type the following: `Papa Franku please come back.`"]
        rand_youtube = random.choice(youtuber_work)
        await ctx.send(rand_dev)
        message = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda : message.author == ctx.author)
        if rand_youtube == youtuber_work[0]:
          if message.content == "I wish I had 100mil sub's like pewdiepie.":
            await ctx.send("You have earned 2000 coins!")
          else:
            await ctx.send("You can't even type a sentence properly? Dumb")
            return
        elif rand_youtube == youtuber_work[1]:
          if message.content == "The Hair Trilogy is the best trilogy to ever exist.":
            await ctx.send("You have earned 2000 coins!")
          else:
            await ctx.send("You can't even type a sentence properly? Dumb")
            return
        elif rand_youtube == youtuber_work[2]:
          if message.content == "Papa Franku please come back.":
            await ctx.send("You have earned 2000 coins!")
          else:
            await ctx.send("You can't even type a sentence properly?")
            return
      #scientist work
      elif id in scientist:
        science_work = ["Type the following: `I wonder if waterproof spray can make me walk on water.`", "Type the following: `Don't trust atoms! They make everything up!`", "Type the following: `No I'm not Elon Musk, I can't make a rocket land by itself.`"]
        rand_science = random.choice(science_work)
        await ctx.send(rand_science)
        message = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda : message.author == ctx.author)
        if rand_science == science_work[0]:
          if message.content == "I wonder if waterproof spray can make me walk on water.":
            await ctx.send("You have earned 2000 coins!")
          else:
            await ctx.send("You can't even type a sentence properly? Dumb")
            return
        elif rand_science == science_work[1]:
          if message.content == "Don't trust atoms! They make everything up!":
            await ctx.send("You have earned 2000 coins!")
          else:
            await ctx.send("You can't even type a sentence properly? Dumb")
            return
        elif rand_science == science_work[2]:
          if message.content == "No I'm not Elon Musk, I can't make a rocket land by itself.":
            await ctx.send("You have earned 2000 coins!")
          else:
            await ctx.send("You can't even type a sentence properly?")
            return
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please post the full traceback error.

Comment: I edited it in.

Comment: Your bot.waitfor checks should take in a parameter

Comment: Hello, I fixed the lambda problem, Im now stuck with the bot not automatically adding your id to the json file.